# Synapse Notebook throws timeout error while connecting to AWS RDS SQL Server

Tags: pyspark, amazon-rds, azure-synapse, azure-notebooks

I am working in the Synapse Workspace and trying to connect to AWS RDS from the Synapse Notebook.

Whenever I try to connect, it throws the below timeout error -

```
The TCP/IP connection to the host my-host, port 1433 has failed. 
Error: "connect timed out. 
Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. 
Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.
```

To check whether I can ping the host from the Synapse Notebook - I tried the below code -

```
import subprocess  
temp = subprocess.Popen(
    ['ping', '-c 1', 'my-host'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE) 

output = str(temp.communicate())
print(output)
```

and this throws

```
ping statistics ---\n1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss
```

I get that this is the timeout error and the notebook cannot reach the server.
What is surprising is, if I try to connect to the same AWS RDS Server by creating a *linked service* from the *Synapse pipeline*, it connects successfully.

On my source AWS RDS, do I need to open the firewall for Synapse notebooks specifically? Is there any endpoint that I should mention in my notebook?

Also, Isn't it handled at the resource group level?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you,

Sanket Kelkar

Answer (score 0):

If you have already configured your database to listen on TCP/IP traffic on port 1433 then it could be any of following three reasons:

- JDBC connection string might be incorrect.
- Firewall is blocking the incoming connection. Make sure that it is publicly accessible. You can check this when you check the availability.
- AWS RDS SQL database is not running. Ensure that "available" is shown as the status.
- make sure you specify the port 1433 while creating SQL server.
- Check to see if your DB instance can be accessed by the inbound rules of your VPC security group. For more information, see  [Can't connect to Amazon RDS DB instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Troubleshooting.html#CHAP_Troubleshooting.Connecting).